# How to extract table from SEC N-Q doc using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

(python 2.7, BeautifulSoup4)

I am trying to extract the table contents from SEC N-Q documents. Sample html here: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/36405/000093247115006447/indexfunds_final.htm

The file has no tag at all. I want to search for section 'C. Futures Contract' and look for the next < table > and extract the contents in < tr >. There are multiple 'C. Futures Contract' occurrences in one document too.

I've tried the following code but got nothing.

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/36405/000093247115006447/indexfunds_final.htm")
futures = soup.find_all(re.compile('C. Futures Contract'))
print futures
```

[ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you are searching by text, use `text` argument (starting from bs 4.4.0 the argument is named [`string`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument)).

Aside from that, for every `futures` section, use [`find_next()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) to find the next `table` element.

Working code:

```
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/36405/000093247115006447/indexfunds_final.htm")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

futures = soup.find_all(text=re.compile('C. Futures Contract'))
for future in futures:
    for row in future.find_next("table").find_all("tr"):
        print [cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all("td")]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! However, why does it only give me one table? I suppose there are 12 'C. Futures Contract' in the document.

Comment: nvm I got it. Changed one line to:

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')