# Extract a table from a locally saved HTML file

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-table, extract

I have a series of HTML files stored in a local folder ("destination folder"). These HTML files all contain a number of tables. What I'm looking to do is to locate the tables I'm interested in thanks to keywords, grab these tables in their entirety, paste them to a text file and save this file to the same local folder ("destination folder").

This is what I have for now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


filename = open('filename.txt', 'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(filename,"lxml")
data = []

for keyword in keywords.split(','):
    u=1
    txtfile = destinationFolder + ticker +'_'+ companyname[:10]+ '_'+item[1]+'_'+item[3]+'_'+keyword+u+'.txt'
    mots = soup.find_all(string=re.compile(keyword))
    for mot in mots:
        for row in mot.find("table").find_all("tr"):
            data = cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all("td")
            data = data.get_string()

        with open(txtfile,'wb') as t:
            t.write(data)

        txtfile.close()

    u=u+1

    except:
       pass

filename.close()
```

Not sure what's happening in the background but I don't get my txt file in the end like I'm supposed to. The process doesn't fail. It runs its course till the end but the txt file is nowhere to be found in my local folder when it's done. I'm sure I'm looking in the correct folder. The same path is used elsewhere in my code and works fine.

Comment: The 10th line is not valid Python code (the line with the `for cell in row`). Was it supposed to be a list comprehension?

Comment: I got it from this stack overflow thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459667/how-to-extract-table-from-sec-n-q-doc-using-beautifulsoup I wasn't sure how it had to be adapted to fit my needs, ie copy and paste into a txt file and then save it locally

Comment: I see. As you said the process didn't fail, I figured you meant the above code would have worked on your system in some way.